# Sveltekit href to endpoint returns an error

Tags: sveltekit

If I try to href a sveltekit endpoint, I can reach the endpoint, and the server process it fine. But I get an error in the frontend console. Is this normal or am I missing something?

```
[from a +page.svelte]
<a href="/api/test">TEST ME</a>
```

```
[api/test/+server.ts]

export async function GET() {
    // Do some magic here... ✨
    return new Response('Hello');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: add `rel="external"` to the a tag.

Reason explained here:
[[breaking] only route pages on the client-side](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/2656)